# How to solve this question on harmonic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

How can I determine $a$ so that the given function is harmonic, and find its harmonic conjugate?

> $$u = e^{\pi x}\cos(av)$$

Where $v$ is itself a real valued function of x,y.

Is there any other method than using Laplace Equation and taking double derivative and solving the equation as it tends to become too complicated?

Comment: $v$ is a real valued function of what?.

Comment: Is $v$ harmonic?

Comment: There must be some hypothesis on $v$; if $v = y$, $a = \pi$ makes $u$ harmonic, but if $v = x$ there is no solution for $a$.

Comment: And in light of my last comment, $v$ harmonic is not the right assumption.

Comment: @RobertLewis v is a function of x and y.

Comment: @RobertLewis I checked the solution, v is harmonic conjugate of u.

Comment: Do you mean to say we are to take $v$ as the conjugate of $u$ as a given?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt.

Use definition of Laplace equation. Solutions of Laplace's equation are harmonic functions.

$f(x,v)=e^{\pi x}cos(av)$

$\Delta f=\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial v^2}=0$

After taking second partials and plugging them into Laplace we get:

$\pi ^{2}cos(av)e^{\pi x}-a^{2}e^{\pi x}cos(av)=0$

$e^{\pi x}cos(av)(\pi ^{2}-a^{2})=0$

$a=\pm \pi$

Comment: Your answer is correct but are you considering v to be independent of x?

Comment: Yes, its the only way that I can make sense of the problem.